# Redirect Form in Javascript passing Values

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

I want to create a form to redirect user to another page according to 3 values:

1) `select` firstcurrency

2) `select` secondcurrency

3) `input` amount

When form is submitted, user must be redirected to the following address:
http://www.example.com/sample/`firstcurrency`-`secondcurrency`/?price=`amount`

Here is the form:

```
<form id="currency">

<input id="amount" name="amount" class="amount" type="text" value="" />

<select id="firstcurrency" class="selex" name="firstcurrency">
<option value="USD">USD</option>
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>

<select id="secondcurrency" class="selex" name="secondcurrency">
<option value="AUD">AUD</option>
<option value="JPY">JPY</option>
</select>

<input class="button" type="submit" value="Redirect Me"/>

</form>
```

What Javascript code would you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .create the object with inner element of the form `name and value` .Then call the object attribute with respected place of the url and assign with `window.location.href` .

> **Note***:for viewing purpose i was added with `var url` .you need to change with `window.location.href=url`

```js
//http://www.example.com/sample/firstcurrency-secondcurrency/?price=amount

function redirect(that){
var params = {};
for( var i=0; i<document.form.elements.length; i++ )
{
   var fieldName = document.form.elements[i].name;
   var fieldValue = document.form.elements[i].value;
   params[fieldName] = fieldValue;
}

console.log(params)
var url ='http://www.example.com/sample/'+params['firstcurrency']+'-'+params['secondcurrency']+'/?price='+params['amount']+''

console.log(url)
return false;
}
```

```html
Here is the form:

<form id="currency" name="form" onsubmit="return redirect(this)">

<input id="amount" name="amount" class="amount" type="text" value="" />

<select id="firstcurrency" class="selex" name="firstcurrency">
<option value="USD">USD</option>
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>

<select id="secondcurrency" class="selex" name="secondcurrency">
<option value="AUD">AUD</option>
<option value="JPY">JPY</option>
</select>

<input class="button" type="submit" value="Redirect Me"/>

</form>
```

**Final version Latest**

```js
function redirect(that) {
  var params = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < document.form.elements.length; i++) {
    var fieldName = document.form.elements[i].name;
    var fieldValue = document.form.elements[i].value;
    params[fieldName] = fieldValue;
  }

  window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/sample/' + params['firstcurrency'] + '-' + params['secondcurrency'] + '/?price=' + params['amount'] + ''
return false;
}
```

```html
Here is the form:

<form id="currency" name="form" onsubmit="return redirect(this)">

  <input id="amount" name="amount" class="amount" type="text" value="" />

  <select id="firstcurrency" class="selex" name="firstcurrency">
<option value="USD">USD</option>
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
</select>

  <select id="secondcurrency" class="selex" name="secondcurrency">
<option value="AUD">AUD</option>
<option value="JPY">JPY</option>
</select>

  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Redirect Me" />

</form>
```

Comment: I've made a few tests but I don't get your modifications. Could you please post the final version?

Comment: @Monzio see my edited answer.i was added final version

Comment: I'm on localhost but I still get redirected to #currenturl#?amount=1&firstcurrency=USD&secondcurrency=AUD

I already include jquery 3.2.1. Any ideas?

Comment: @Monzio yes i knew it..try latest updated one.surely its working .i was tested

Answer (score 0):

```
function Redirect(){
  //Get values of the elements by their id

  var firstcurrency = document.getElementById('firstcurrency').value;
  var secondcurrency = document.getElementById('firstcurrency').value;
  var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;

  //Redirect with javascript
  window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/sample/"+firstcurrency+"-"+secondcurrency+"/?price="+amount);
}
```

And on the submit button:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Redirect Me" onclick="Redirect()"/>
```

Comment: I get redirected to #CURRENTURL#/?amount=4&firstcurrency=USD&secondcurrency=AUD

Comment: try `window.location.href` instead of `window.location.replace`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
var form = document.getElementById('currency');
form.onsubmit = function(e){

    var firstcurrency = document.getElementById('firstcurrency').value;
    var secondcurrency = document.getElementById('secondcurrency').value;
    var price = document.getElementById('amount').value;

    e.target.action = "http://www.example.com/sample/"+firstcurrency+"-"+secondcurrency+"/?price="+price;

}
```

Also, to achieve the exact same url scheme, you will have to remove the name attributes of all your input elements, lest they will be appended at end of the URL as query params.

Here's the updated form:

```
<form id="currency" >
    <input id="amount" class="amount" type="text" value="" />

    <select id="firstcurrency" class="selex" >
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    </select>

    <select id="secondcurrency" class="selex" >
    <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
    <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
    </select>

    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Redirect Me"/>
</form>
```